# Exporting a DimensionReducerFunction

Tags: export, machine-learning, dimension-reduction, external-calls

I need to run my `DimensionReducerFunction` in a standalone fashion outside of MMA. That is, without calling into a kernel or through an APIFunction.

For example, with "Autoencoder" it is possible to extract the inner NetGraphs, but recreating the pre/post processing might be impossible:

```
dr = DimensionReduction[RandomReal[{0,3},{1000, 10}], Method->"Autoencoder"]
```

[image]

Are there any known ways of achieving this for any of the supported dimension reduction methods?

**Notes:**

- Preferably, it would run in javascript (I have a react app and I need this to run in browser), but I'll accept any external language runtime.